# Trying to add a column (alter a table) through postdeployment scripts and trying to add data into the newly created column throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

We use post-deployment scripts to maintain history of the data in the tables. I am trying to add a new column to the existing table through post deployment script. I have written a post-deployment script to add the new column and one more post deployment script to add data into the newly inserted column.I am trying to publish my database then I can see my alter table script before adding data but it throws an error `'Invalid column name 'NewlyAddedColumn''` My question can we alter the schema using post deployment scripts? I tried using Commit command after altering the table in the post deployment but still encountered the same error message. I am running the post-deployment script to add new column before accessing it to insert data.Could some one help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Right-click on the post deployment script, go to the properties and set Build = none. But why do you want to add column in the post script? Why don't you want to add it to the project?

Comment: I see that it's already selected as none. We would like to have versioning so that we have the information about in which versions what changes are made. The post deployment scripts are added as when we deploy changes to the database are done as they were created in the versions they came up.